# Finding the coordinates of a letter placed on TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a textview which contains longs text that covers half of the screen,

In this textview I have two words at different position above which I have to place a blank layout which will give it a glass effect.

I can do this by placing the textview in a framelayout and placing the layout above it.

The problem is how will I get the coordinates of the words, as the text may be arranged at different position on different devices.

[image]

I want to place a layout at the place marked white. Can some one please help
Thanks.

Comment: I had did same but only for links using `spannable` string.. If you want to do same please check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683076/urlspan-in-spannablestring ..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be helpful for you

> ```
> public void getLocationOnScreen (int[] location)
>     Since: API Level 1
>
> Computes the coordinates of this view on the screen. The argument must be an
> array of two integers. After the method returns, the array contains the x and y
> location in that order.
>
> Parameters
>    location   an array of two integers in which to hold the coordinates
> ```

See [this](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/test-runner/src/android/test/ViewAsserts.java.shtml) code, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) link, and also [this](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/awt/Component/getLocationOnScreen%28%29.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can get the coordinates for the text directly from TextView - you should search inside TextView class source code. But.... if you render the textview as bitmap and then to seach inside the bitmap the coordinates of the text (if the searched text is blue should be easy to get the rectangle!

Answer (score -1):

What you really want here is a backgroundspan :

```
span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE);
text.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```